# Need help on how to make first accordion tab opened by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I want the first tab of this acordion to be opened by default.

Here is the code for it on codepen: https://codepen.io/villa7/pen/grPddp

It probably has something to do with this:

```
input:checked + .box {
    height: auto;
    margin: 16px 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.16),0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.32);
}
```

Comment: Just add checked to the first radio input: `<input type="radio" checked name="accordion" id="cb1" />` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xoPXvO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `checked` to the first radio input, so that it will act like it's checked already. This will expand the first accordion automatically, there is no need to use anything else unless you need to programmatically set this.

```
<input type="radio" checked name="accordion" id="cb1" />
```

Working codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xoPXvO

Working example:

```css
body {
 height: calc(100% - 20px);
 width: calc(100% - 20px);
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10px;
 display: flex;
 background: #f2f2f2;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,.87);
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.accordion {
 margin: auto;
 width: 400px;
}
.accordion input {
 display: none;
}
.box {
 position: relative;
 background: white;
    height: 64px;
    transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
}
.box::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #e5e5e5,0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.12),0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.24);
}
header.box {
 background: #00BCD4;
 z-index: 100;
 cursor: initial;
 box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #e5e5e5,0 0 2px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.12),0 2px 4px -4px rgba(0,0,0,.24);
}
header .box-title {
 margin: 0;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 16pt;
 color: white;
 cursor: initial;
}
.box-title {
 width: calc(100% - 40px);
 height: 64px;
 line-height: 64px;
 padding: 0 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;-webkit-user-select: none;-khtml-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;
}
.box-content {
 width: calc(100% - 40px);
 padding: 30px 20px;
 font-size: 11pt;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,.54);
 display: none;
}
.box-close {
 position: absolute;
 height: 64px;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: none;
}
input:checked + .box {
 height: auto;
 margin: 16px 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.16),0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.32);
}
input:checked + .box .box-title {
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.18);
}
input:checked + .box .box-content,
input:checked + .box .box-close {
 display: inline-block;
}
.arrows section .box-title {
 padding-left: 44px;
 width: calc(100% - 64px);
}
.arrows section .box-title:before {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 content: '\203a';
 font-size: 18pt;
 left: 20px;
 top: -2px;
 transition: transform .15s ease-in-out;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,.54);
}
input:checked + section.box .box-title:before {
 transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
 <nav class="accordion arrows">
  <header class="box">
   <label for="acc-close" class="box-title">Accordion menu</label>
  </header>
  <input type="radio" checked name="accordion" id="cb1" />
  <section class="box">
   <label class="box-title" for="cb1">Readme</label>
   <label class="box-close" for="acc-close"></label>
   <div class="box-content">Click on an item to open. Click on its header or the list header to close.</div>
  </section>
  <input type="radio" name="accordion" id="cb2" />
  <section class="box">
   <label class="box-title" for="cb2">Read me too</label>
   <label class="box-close" for="acc-close"></label>
   <div class="box-content">Add the class 'arrows' to nav.accordion to add dropdown arrows.</div>
  </section>
  <input type="radio" name="accordion" id="cb3" />
  <section class="box">
   <label class="box-title" for="cb3">Item 3</label>
   <label class="box-close" for="acc-close"></label>
   <div class="box-content">Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque finibus tristique nisi, maximus ullamcorper ante finibus eget.</div>
  </section>

  <input type="radio" name="accordion" id="acc-close" />
 </nav>
</body>
```